# How to get a subset of a table using the count operator

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

SQL Server 2012.

Each enterprise has one or more teams. Each team can have sponsors or cannot have any sponsors.

```
Enterprise

Id    Name
1      A
2      B
3      C
```

and the team table:

```
Team

Id    Name    EnterpiseId
1      For         1
2      Xor         2
3      Nor         2
4      Xur         1
5      Fir         3
6      Fte         2
```

and now the table sponsor

```
Sponsor

id     Name    TeamId
1      XX1        1
2      FC7        1
3      89U        3
```

Now I need to know how to present this table that shows only the enterprises that have at least one sponsor.

```
FINAL TABLE

Id    Name
1      A
3      C
```

The enterprise B has 3 teams, but there are no sponsors for those 3 teams, so I want to show the enterprises that have sponsors which are "A" and "C".

```
Select A.id, A.name
FROM Enterprise A
LEFT JOIN Team B on A.Id=b.EnterpriseId
INNER JOIN Sponsor C on B.Id=C.TeamId
Where (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Sponsor S INNER JOIN Team T on T.id=S.TeamId group by T.id)>0
```

This is not working. I am not used to use subsets which is likely the way to achieve the desired table. Thanks.

Comment: Does "cannot have any sponsors" mean "can have zero sponsors"?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `JOIN`s.  The `GROUP BY` is just to eliminate duplicates:

```
SELECT e.id, e.name
FROM Enterprise e JOIN
     Team t
     ON e.Id = t.EnterpriseId JOIN
     Sponsor s
     ON t.Id = s.TeamId
GROUP BY e.id, e.name;
```

The `JOIN` only matches teams that have sponsors.

If you were looking for more than one, then something like `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` would be called for.